# Error during the creation of hidden fields for nested objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using rails 2.3.5. I have a Blog model and Blog has many comments. This is my Blog controller show action

```
def show
  @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Comment.new
end
```

I would display the Blog and at the end would have an option for creating comment. So I add this in blogs/show.html.erb.

```
<% form_remote_for  @comment do |f| %>
      <%= f.label :content %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 6 %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :blog => @blog %>
      <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

But i get the following error when i run this
NoMethodError in Blogs#show

Showing app/views/blogs/show.html.erb where line #270 raised:

```
undefined method `blog#<Blog:0xb677d8d0>' for #<Comment:0xb67762b0>
```

Extracted source (around line #270):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to hide the id of the blog not the blog object.

```
<%= f.hidden_field :blog_id%>
```

Answer (score 2):

`Comment` model should have `belongs_to :blog`

`Blog` model should have `has_many :comments`

Initialize the comment in the controller like this:

```
@blog.comments.new
```

The view should be like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :blog_id %>
```

Comment: to     '@comment' only with     '@comment = @blog.comments.build'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `f.hidden_field` line. The first parameter should be the attribute name of the `@comment` you want in the field, but in your code it's a Hash.

I'd suggest adjusting your `show` action to set `@comment = @blog.comments.build`, and change the view to read `f.hidden_field :blog_id`.